# Run exchange management shell once

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server

we are executing some exchange powershell commands using asp c# - all works fine
the biggest problem is the connection time to the exchange server by using

```
$s = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://mail.xxx.xxx/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos"
Import-PSSession $s
```

the import-pssession takes up to 20sec which is to much

is it possible to start the powershell(inluding exchange commands) once and send only the commands to the shell without a new connection?

thanks

Comment: Nothing to do with [tag:asp-classic]...

Comment: partly - maybe this is working in the same way for other applications - start application once and access it without open it again...